# Running Command "docker-compose run web ..." creates a new container in Kitematic container list

Tags: docker, docker-compose, kitematic

Each time I run the command "docker-compose run web ..." it results in another container being added to Kitematic, so that I have a list of containers like "image-name_web_run_1" and so on with each run of docker-compose.

Is this expected behaviour? If so, how do I work around it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is expected. You can use `docker-compose run --rm` to have the container removed when it exits.

You can clean up these old containers using `docker-compose down` or `docker-compose rm -a`.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean new container? That is the expected behavior for `docker-compose run`, see: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/

Did you mean to use `docker-compose exec`? 
e.g., `docker-compose exec web /bin/sh`
See: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/exec/

Comment: I was trying to run a container command directly from the command line. Yes I mean container.

Comment: To run a container command you can use `docker-compose exec` e.g., `docker-compose exec web /bin/sh` which is equivalent to `docker exec -ti web /bin/sh`. See: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/exec/ . (answer updated to reflect your comment.)

Comment: If you were trying to run a command on a running container, then `docker exec` (or `docker-compose exec`) is what you are looking for. `docker-compose run --rm` will create and destroy a temporary container, which is more expensive and may have some side-effects. In basic cases, they will pretty much do the same thing, so it may not matter -- just depends what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that some users want something in the middle of the out of the box functionality for `exec` vs `run`.

`docker-compose run` stands up a new container, that then needs to be cleaned up.

`docker-compose exec` only works on an existing and RUNNING container, which errors out if the container is not running.

As far as I know there is not a command or "one-liner" to accomplish the desired effect of starting a potentially stopped container and running a one-off command.

If you want to avoid the expense of creating a new container and then destroying it every time as suggested in the accepted answer by using the `--rm` flag; as pointed out in [ldg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/786662/ldg)'s comment.

Then you have to manually start the container and then run `exec` to get the desired effect.

I recommend the following concatenated commands:

```
 docker-compose start web; docker-compose exec web bin/rails c
```

NOTE: assuming you have dependencies set up in your docker-compose file, those will also be started with the `start` command.